# Why does a large amount of AppSettings calls to a none existent key cause application crashes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, windows-services, crash

There is a very strange problem with a Windows Service I am working on that I would like to understand why it occurs.

The service loops every 5 minutes and then within that loop it loops through keys containing webservice URLs that are numbered such as:

```
<add key="URL.1" value="http://dummy1.com/Service.asmx"/>
<add key="URL.2" value="http://dummy2.com/Service.asmx"/>
<add key="URL.3" value="http://dummy3.com/Service.asmx"/>
```

The code that does this check is:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(AppSettings("OM." & intCount & ".Name").ToString) Then
```

When it hits a key that doesn't exist an exception is thrown and the service stops and waits for 5 minutes until the next loop.

This usually works great but every week or two the Windows service will crash on that line without any Exception. The application log has a line from before that line but nothing after, none of the Try Catches are hit (the main one is catching the base "Exception" class).

In the Event Log for Windows is the following:

```
Faulting application name: MyService.exe, version: 1.1.2.0, time stamp: 0x4fa22a24
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xe053534f
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

The weird part is that this line of code is executing fine 300 times a day for at least a week which is around 2000 times before that one time it causes a full crash of the application.

Any ideas why this is occurring? I have changed that line of code to not rely on Exceptions and it has been working fine for a week now with no crash so could be something to do with too many Exceptions - maybe causing a stack overflow?

Answer (score 1):

> Exception code: 0xe053534f

Your program is crashing with this site's name.  The last 3 hex pairs of the exception code are the ascii codes for "SSO".  Which means "Soft Stack Overflow".  It is the same thing as a hard stack overflow exception, except that it got detected early.  While setting up a call and the CLR noticing that actually making the call was going to cause a hard stack overflow.

Your program will otherwise crash just like it would on a hard StackOverflowException, it is an immediate abort with no catch blocks or AppDomain.UnhandledException getting executed.

Exactly how your program suffered this fate is undiagnosable from the question.  It is otherwise a typical programming bug.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it was a stack overflow. I think not relying on the exceptions in the code has stopped it from occurring.